# Connection to different databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing data into database, approve it via a php script and write it to a second database to be stored.

I get the error:

> Invalid SQL: UPDATE data_base2.table_name SET WHERE acct_id = 'sample'

If I use the command without the database name it works:

UPDATE table_name SET WHERE acct_id = 'sample'

Could it be the way I address the table? Do I have to use the dbo: [databasename].[dbo].[some_table].

database and table structure are fine since they are in use without errors

Comment: That's not a PHP generated error I'm familiar with. Is that what you're actually getting? If not, please show the full error message, and if it is, I would assume you've got some code elsewhere hiding the more specific error. But your issue is that you don't have anything between SET and WHERE.

Comment: `SET WHERE` looks as though it's missing something.

Comment: There should be a statement in between SET and WHERE so you actually set content in the row. E.g. `UPDATE data_base2.table_name SET my_column = 'hello world' WHERE acct_id = 'sample'`

Comment: Thank you. Have to see if I can get the full SQL error message

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ocurring due to your SQL Syntax.

You're trying:

```
UPDATE data_base2.table_name SET WHERE acct_id = 'sample'
```

It seems that you're forgetting to inform the column (and the value) you want to update:

```
UPDATE data_base2.table_name SET COLUMN = VALUE WHERE acct_id = 'sample'
```

Can you see the difference?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to find where the SQL syntax is in my code. I have the feeling I am addressing the database wrong, since the script works when I use other tables. I just found this order [databasename].[dbo].[some_table].